# Adding links to a D3 map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, hyperlink

I'm new to D3 and have been making graphs based on the examples at http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033 and http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/.  I found out elsewhere on this site ([D3 tree graph with links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230133/d3-tree-graph-with-links)) how to link the node labels in the tree graph to another page.  However, when I tried something similar with the map, it simply didn't work and I'm trying to figure out why.  I've used the Firefox web inspector to see more of what's really happening in the output, but am still confused.  The links in the tree diagram look like this in the web inspector:

```
<a xlink:href="www.example.com">
  <text style="fill-opacity: 1;" text-anchor="end" dy=".35em" x="-10">Example text</text>
</a>
```

These work like any other link would.  The ones in the map look like this:

```
<a xlink:href="www.example.com">
  <text style="text-anchor: end; fill: yellow;" dy=".35em" x="-6" transform="translate(1181.2709561800666,621.4893776251483)" class="place-label">Example text</text>
</a>
```

These don't work at all.  The text displays as it should, but nothing happens if I click on them.  Here's the code I'm using to generate them:

```
svg.selectAll(".place-label")
.data(places.features)
.enter().append("a")
.attr("xlink:href", function(d) {return "www.example.com"})    
.append("text")
.attr("class", "place-label")
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + projection(d.geometry.coordinates) + ")"; })
.attr("x", function(d) { return d.geometry.coordinates[0] > -1 ? 6 : -6; })
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.geometry.coordinates[0] > -1 ? "start" : "end"; })
.style("fill", function(d) {return d.properties.level;})
.text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; });
```

Note that the "level" property in the next-to-last line comes from a column I added to the file containing city information in CSV form before I converted it to JSON and the value assigned to the "href" attribute will be replaced with something based on another column I added to this file.

Update: I tried changing the code to this:

```
svg.selectAll(".place-label")
.data(places.features)
.enter()
.append("g")
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + projection(d.geometry.coordinates) + ")"; })
.append("a")
.attr("xlink:href", function(d) {return "www.example.com"})    
.append("text")
.attr("class", "place-label")
.attr("x", function(d) { return d.geometry.coordinates[0] > -1 ? 6 : -6; })
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.geometry.coordinates[0] > -1 ? "start" : "end"; })
.style("fill", function(d) {return d.properties.level;})
.text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; });
```

Clicking on them still does nothing.

The corresponding HTML now looks like this:

```
<g transform="translate(1181.2709561800666,621.4893776251483)">
  <a xlink:href="www.example.com">
    <text style="text-anchor: end; fill: yellow;" dy=".35em" x="-6" class="place-label">Example Text</text>
  </a>
</g>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work at all." Is the link text visible but nothing happens when you click it? Or does the link not appear at all?

Comment: You must have read my question very soon after I posted it.  I realized that may need to be clarified and edited it, adding: The text displays as it should, but nothing happens if I click on them.

Comment: I wonder if the transform is confusing the browser. What happens if you put the anchor tag in a group and transform that group instead of the text element?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally.  Here's what the script's style section has for text elements:

```
text {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Commenting out "pointer-events: none;" was all it took.